Why gradient flow cannot have a closed orbit on compact surface?
When I read the Hamilton's The Ricci flow on surfaces (237- 262 of this), the author said "a greadient flow cannot have a closed orbit" in the 257th page. I want to  know why.
Assume $M$ is a compact surface, $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is smooth. The greadient field of $f$ is $\nabla f$. Assume the flow of $\nabla f$ is $\varphi_t$, namely,
$$
\partial_t \phi_t(p) =\nabla f (\phi_t(p))
$$
Then, how to show that for any $p\in M$, $\phi_t(p)$ can not be a closed curve ?

Even if the real world analogy can lead to errors, you can think here of what a closed orbit for gradient flow mean for water over hills. As the water follows the height gradient (of course downside...), a closed orbit would mean the a river could reach its spring....

A key fact about the gradient flow of $f$ is that $f(p)$ is a strictly increasing function from the beginning to the end of each nonstationary path of the gradient flow: applying the chain rule we have
$$\frac{d}{dt} f(\phi_t(p)) = \nabla f(\phi_t(p)) \cdot \partial_t \phi_t(p) = \nabla f(\phi_t(p)) \cdot \nabla f(\phi_t(p)) \ge 0
$$
with strict inequality unless the gradient is zero at every point of $\phi_t(p)$, including at $p$ itself, in which case $p$ is a stationary point of the flow (which is not a closed curve).
So if there were to exist a nonstationary $p \in M$ and some $t>0$ such that $\phi_t(p)=p$ then $f(p) > f(p)$.
